# Sonarqube Database Upgrade taking forever

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.6

I am trying to Upgrade from 
SonarQube 4.5.1 to 5.6.6. It had been 2 weeks, and the upgrade is still running. The underlying database is Oracle. I have around 1,610,000 issues. However the Upgrade is processing only 4 records in a sec. Please advice, is there a way to tweak, to make it faster.

2017.04.11 08:15:49 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.MassUpdate] 1593749 issues processed (4 items/sec)

Comment: I have added commas to your issue count. Do you really have the right number of zeros in there?

Comment: yes...We have multiple projects in the same sonar instance. So higher issues

Comment: A few millions of issues are not so many. The upgrade should be much faster. I recommend to contact DBA and system admin to monitor the database and the network to DB.

Comment: Checked that as well..All seems well..infact, the database and Server are located in the same location, with no latency..i faced similar issue..when i tried to upgrade to 5.2. I had to abandon it, and roll over the DB to continue working on 4.5.2

Comment: Did you have a look at the SonarQube log files?

Comment: Yes jeroen.. I checked the logs..no errors or nothing unusual

Comment: @KanakaSubramaniam look your log with a tail -f you should see activity with select, update on all tables.The log has to evolve very regularly and you have to see current update, which changes every minute or more often. Tell us what are the last logs ?

Comment: @kanaka-subramaniam Did you ever find a solution? I'm running into this going from 5.6.7 to 6.7

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue going from 5.6.7 to 6.7. Estimated update time would be days, if not weeks for 75 measures in dev and 1.6 million in prod.

We added 2 indexes and it took about 7 minutes for 75k measures.

```
create index sonar_dba.measures_snapshot_id on sonar_dba.project_measures (snapshot_id) tablespace sonar;
create index sonar_dba.measures_sid_metric on sonar_dba.project_measures (id, metric_id) tablespace sonar;
```

Good luck.